# Scikit-learn: which values are provided to a scorer by default when needs_threshold=True?

Tags: scikit-learn

In a binary classification setting, tuning a model based on area under the ROC requires a model output that can be thresholded.

However, in scikit-learn, support vector classifiers do not generate class probabilities by default.

So for example, using `GridSearchCV` with `scoring=make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_threshold=False)` to tune an `SVC` model is incorrect because the AUC scores will be calculated based on predicted *classes* in each CV fold. This will occur regardless of whether we use `SVC(probability=True)` or `SVC(probability=False)`. On the other hand, `scoring=make_scorer(roc_auc_score, needs_threshold=True)` will tune correctly.

Therefore `SVC` must be passing some "thresholdable" output to the scoring function in `GridSearchCV`. **How can we know what this thresholdable output is for a given model?**

For `SVC` I assume that the `decision_function()` method is called. (I assume it is not calculating class probabilities because you cannot run `predict_proba()` on the fitted `GridSearchCV` object when using `SVC(probability=False)`). But it is not clear (to me at least) from the documentaion that this is definitely what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

From the [source-code of make_scorer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L447):

```
....
elif needs_threshold:
    cls = _ThresholdScorer
....
```

So when `needs_threshold = True`,  a `_ThresholdScorer` scorer is used. Now looking into the [source code of `_ThresholdScorer`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py#L174), we see this:

```
....
....
        try:
            y_pred = clf.decision_function(X)

            # For multi-output multi-class estimator
            if isinstance(y_pred, list):
                y_pred = np.vstack(p for p in y_pred).T

        except (NotImplementedError, AttributeError):
            y_pred = clf.predict_proba(X)
```

So, this will first call `decision_function()` of the estimator for finding the thresholds.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you